# Написать SQL запрос к базе данных

Tags: sql

Дана таблица с полями:

```
post_id         // - номер в отеле
room_parent     //- отель
multi_location
id_location 
address
allow_full_day 
price number_room
discount_rate
adult_number   //- максимальное кол-во взрослых в номере
extra_bed
child_number
```

Как написать запрос, выводящий максимальное кол-во людей в каждом отеле

Моя попытка написать запрос, которая не удачна:

```
SELECT room_parent,
       post_id,
       adult_number
  FROM wp_hotel_room
 WHERE post_id = (SELECT post_id 
                    FROM wp_hotel_room
                  HAVING MAX(adult_number))
```

Comment: Хорошо бы таблицы представить в удобном виде  - в глазах рябит от черточек

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов, изменил настолько, насколько позволяет функционал данного сайта

Comment: По правилам форума вряд ли кто напишет Вам запрос, хотя это делается в три минуты, пока Вы дадите вариант своего решения. Здесь помогают, а не делают чужую работу.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов, а какой толк писать заедомо неправильные запросы? Ну вот, мой один из неверных запросов: SELECT `room_parent`,`post_id`,`adult_number` FROM `wp_hotel_room` WHERE `post_id`=(SELECT `post_id` FROM `wp_hotel_room` HAVING MAX(`adult_number`))

Comment: @Alexey_Danilov вы не понимаете сути данного ресурса и скорее всего не ознакомились с рекомендациями публикации вопросов:
Во-первых, здесь принято не выполнять работу за других, а помогать решать возникающие проблемы. 
Во-вторых, вы не ознакомились с рекомендациями о том, как задавать вопросы.
Ссылочка на рекомендации: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Жак-ИвКусто, я не прошу всю работу за меня выполнить. Я много времени потратил на составление запросов, у меня не вышло, поэтому обратился сюда. В комменте выше и в самом вопросе написал пример своего неудачного запроса

Comment: @Alexey_Danilov Вы снова не прочли рекомендации. Дело в том, что подобные вопросы 1000 раз уже как были заданы и столько же решены: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134161/sql-join-group-by-count

Comment: И еще один момент - если Вы хотите чтобы с Вами на форуме разговаривали - обязательно нужно давать свой вариант решения, даже если он не удачен.

Comment: Я конечно могу поздно вечером ошибиться, но "максимальное кол-во людей в каждом отеле" в Вашей структуре таблицы это yне что иное как сумма по всем комнатам в отеле то есть "SELECT [room_parent], SUM([adult_number]) as MaxNumber FROM [wp_hotel_room] Group By [room_parent]" пожалуйста уточните, что Вам нужно.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов , вот так выглядит правильный вариант: SELECT `room_parent`, MAX(`child_number`) FROM `wp_hotel_room` GROUP BY `room_parent`

Comment: Ваш вариант, который Вы назвали правильным, не соответствует тому, что Вы спрашивали. Я кажется просил Вас уточнить Ваш вопрос. Вы отняли время не только у меня, но и тех людей, которые просматривали вопрос и пытались на него ответить

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов, да, вы правы, я задал некорректный вопрос..сейчас ещё раз перечитал его

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `room_parent`, MAX(`child_number`) 
FROM `wp_hotel_room` 
GROUP BY `room_parent`
```